# Are calls to an automation server executed in the main thread like this?

Tags: delphi, com, automation, delphi-7, ole

My Delphi7 application is also an automation server, registered the following way:

```
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TMyServer, Class_App,
    ciMultiInstance, tmSingle);
```

In this case does the tmSingle threading model mean that all calls to the automation server are executed in the application's main thread? Meaning that I don't have to call synchronize and worry about writing to variables on my application's main form, even if other applications are using multiple instances of my automation server in the same time? There is very little information in the delphi helps about this, and I'd like to make sure that I'm not violating thread safety.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Win.ComObj.TThreadingModel  --  `tmSingle : COM serializes all client requests. The object does not need to provide thread support. `

Comment: Serializes all client requests within the automation server's own thread (meaning that the automation server's thread is created only once) or within the application's main thread too? I read that part of the documentation before asking, but it's far from clear, that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: You seem to use the word "application" both for for the client (the process making a COM call) and the server (the process executing said call). Is yours an in-proc server (a DLL) or an out-of-proc server (an EXE)? When you say "my application's main form", what does "application" refer to here - the server or the client?

Comment: It is an EXE. So there is the application, and the automation server within the exe, and the automation server wants to call the application's main form, while multiple programs may be using the automation server.

Comment: Instead of having a discussion in comments, [edit] your question and make it more clear what you're asking, and clarify your terminology. You seem to be randomly mixing server, client, and application interchangeably, and they're not.

Answer (score 0):

Your out-of-process server is its own process. So by default it's single threaded.

This holds even if the process spawning it might be multi-threaded.